# Would rendering problems occur on Microsoft edge browser if I use '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />'?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am working on maintenance of an existing website which works well on IE11 and below, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. But when I try to run the website on Microsoft edge browser, it has some issues regarding the rendering of JSPs and HTML pages.

In my exisitng code, the following meta tag is present:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

which is clearly pointing information regarding being designed for IE7.

So my question now is, with the above line in the code, would it cause rendering issues on MS Edge browser?

I would be also extra grateful of somebody tells me the browser compatibility in regards to the meta content.

Comment: Can you provide some details about the issues you have? Or even a link to the page? As BoltClock already mentioned, Edge will ignore the X-UA-Compatible flag. The behavoir in Edge should therefore be pretty much the same as in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft Edge will ignore the X-UA-Compatible header.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn904497.aspx#document_modes) For most people, this is good news, but if your site was designed to work with legacy versions of IE, chances are it won't work well on Microsoft Edge (though it seems odd that it'd work well on Chrome and Firefox if that's the case).

You'll need to ask your users to use IE, though Microsoft Edge also provides an option within the app to open a page in IE.